# What are these dots appearing on my model in the 3D View?

Tags: 3d-view

[image]I am trying to model something and these keep coming up.

I have tried several buttons and none of them turn it off. This is in Blender 2.8 beta.

[image]

How do I fix this?

Comment: For me it looks like some kind of GPU driver / incompatibility issue. Maybe try some different Blender version, nightly build or GPU drivers?

Comment: @JanKadeřábek Apparently, you are correct. It says no compatible GPU's were found, how do I fix this without getting a new version of blender?

Comment: @DannyGreff You do not loose any reputation or anything when someone edits your posts. They are just trying to help. You are still the OP, and you will get the votes.

Comment: Updating your GPU driver isn't too hard. Firstoff, locate what type of GPU you're using in the first place. You can find that by going to the Device-Manager in windows. Once you know what kind of gpu you have literally google "*GPU NAME HERE* drivers". Use the official sites from NVidia or AMD rather than third-party ones, and follow the instructions there.

Comment: It may help to set triple buffering File->User Preferences->System Set Window Draw Method to Triple Buffer.

Comment: Thanks a lot, everyone. @IAmGettingTiredOfAliases I have searched for my Intel(R) HD Graphics 620 and I believe I have found something, but Intel has now added an automatic computer scan that checks for any Intel driver updates. Thanks again!